# Does `build-storybook` work for react-native?

Tags: react-native, storybook

I'm trying to export my storybook as a static app as described in https://storybook.js.org/docs/basics/exporting-storybook/.

However when i run `build-storybook -c ./storybook -o .out`, i get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../Utilities/BackHandler' in .../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native`.

Am I getting this error simply because `build-storybook` does not work for react-native or is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure what the state of things is on the latest storybook version with react native but we had to use a custom webpack config to render our stories using react-native-web in order to export a static storybook site.

Comment: Hi, @Azundo can you provide a link to your sample storybook with native-web,  even I'm getting the same error, I think that would be definitely a greate workaround